# How to rename PDF file, with texts extracted from the PDF file?

Tags: python, pdf, rename

I am trying to use Python to rename PDF file using part of the file content. Here is the situation.

The PDF file is a commercial invoice, contains wordings "Commercial Invoice" and "Department". I want to rename the file to "Commercial Invoice" and " Department ", such as "353624 HR".

Here is what I have so far:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pyPdf
import os

# a function here
def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    num_pages = 10
    p = file(path, "rb")
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(p)
    for i in range(0, num_pages):
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
        content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())     
        return content 

# name of the source PDF file
PDF_name = '222'

# picking texts from the PDF file
pdfContent = StringIO(getPDFContent("C:\\" + PDF_name + ".pdf").encode("ascii", "ignore"))
for line in pdfContent:
    aaa = line.find(' Commercial Invoice ')
    CIN = line[aaa + 28: aaa + 38]
    bbb = line.find('Department')
    Dpt = line [bbb+20 : bbb+26]

    final_name = str(CIN + " " + Dpt)
    
print final_name

f = open("C:\\" + PDF_name + ".pdf")
f.close()

os.rename("C:\\" + PDF_name + ".pdf", "C:\\" + final_name + ".pdf")
```

it works until print out the text extracted ' print final_name', but at the last part when renaming the file, it gives an error " WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

What went wrong here? it seems the file was once not closed properly?

Comment: p.close and return content should be out of for loop .

Comment: thanks, vks. indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `def getPDFContent(path)`,
after `p = file(path, "rb")`,
when the content has been copied,
you need to close the file.

```
p.close()
```

put this just after the for loop but in the function.

Comment: thanks vks. it works! i tried a few and found it only works closing the 'p' in the 'for' loop, before 'return content '.

Comment: yes coz file descriptor attached to file was open and so windows when again went for opening the file found it being locked by another process which was actually the p in the above function. :)

Answer (score -1):

Add `C:\\` also to your PDF_name in the last line.

Comment: thanks Emanuele for the fast response. i added the "c:\\" but the problem seems lie on the file closure. could you please help again? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done through mouse_event and cursor position
Below is the code :

```
Sub Run_report1()

'
' Run_report Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+G
'
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
SendKeys "%{Tab}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")


Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do Until i > 8
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")


SetCursorPos 309, 253

mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

SendKeys "{Enter}", True


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")

SetCursorPos 794, 771

mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")


SetCursorPos 1068, 728

mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

SetCursorPos 746, 94

mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")


SendKeys "%{Tab}", True

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

SetCursorPos 309, 253

mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

SendKeys "^V", True
SendKeys "{Enter}", True

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

SendKeys "{F5}", True

SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True
SendKeys "{PGUP}", True

i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox "Task Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: @Saket Kapoor, thank you for sharing! However, the question was meant for Python. :)