# Permission Error when Renaming all PDFs in a directory

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am creating a program that will rename a series of PDFs within a specific directory based on their contents. I've got the contents extracted into a string, but os.rename() is not able to change the name because the file is open already. I found [a nearly identical solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859261/how-to-rename-pdf-file-with-texts-extracted-from-the-pdf-file), but I've not been able to implement it properly.  I feel like I'm pretty close to perfect functionality, but I don't know where to put load_pdf.close(), or if I need to phrase it differently. Wherever I put it either throws the same error or some other error that would lead to certain failure.

```
import PyPDF2
import os

for file_name in os.listdir('upload_12.5.22_test'):
    load_pdf = open('C:/Users/Jake/Documents/upload_12.5.22_test/'+file_name,'rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(load_pdf)
    page_count = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    data_page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = data_page.extractText()
    page_content = page_content.replace('\n','')
    page_content = page_content.split('reports.')
    del page_content[0:1]
    p_c_str = ''.join(page_content)
    p_c_str = p_c_str.strip()
    p_c_str = p_c_str[:-6]
    p_c_str = p_c_str + " agreement"
    load_pdf.close()
    os.rename('C:/Users/Jake/Documents/upload_12.5.22_test/'+file_name, 'C:/Users/Jake/Documents/upload_12.5.22_test/'+p_c_str+".pdf")
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\progam1.py", line 30, in <module>
    os.rename('C:/Users/Jake/Documents/upload_12.5.22_test/'+file_name, 'C:/Users/Jake/Documents/upload_12.5.22_test/'+p_c_str+".pdf")
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/Jake/Documents/upload_12.5.22_test/First M Last agreement.pdf' -> 'C:/Users/Jake/Documents/upload_12.5.22_test/First Last agreement.pdf'
[Finished in 456ms]
```

**UPDATE:** I have found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66606778/how-do-i-solve-permissionerror-winerror-32-when-renaming-files-with-pypdf2-s), which seems to be addressing the issue. So, I am calling os.rename() improperly, and trying to change the active file directory. So, I've moved everything into a single directory to eliminate any errors from linking to the direct source, but It's still throwing the exact same error, so I'm back to where I started.

```
import PyPDF2
import os

for file_name in os.listdir():
    load_pdf = open(file_name,'rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(load_pdf)
    page_count = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    data_page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = data_page.extractText()
    page_content = page_content.replace('\n','')
    page_content = page_content.split('reports.')
    del page_content[0:1]
    p_c_str = ''.join(page_content)
    p_c_str = p_c_str.strip()
    p_c_str = p_c_str[:-6]
    p_c_str = p_c_str + " agreement"
    load_pdf.close()
    os.rename(file_name, p_c_str+".pdf")
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Work Projects\Python\Contract Extraction\upload_12.5.22_test\contract_extraction_testing_2.py", line 28, in <module>
    os.rename(file_name, p_c_str+".pdf")
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Alan R Diaz agreement.pdf' -> 'Alan Diaz agreement.pdf'
[Finished in 205ms]
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your code and there is no way to fix it in the code. The OS (Windows) does not let you modify a file while it is in use by another process, as the error says. Close the other process which is locking the file.

Comment: This is one of those annoying things about windows. It's not the most elegant solution, but if you can't figure out what you need to close to make windows happy, sometimes rebooting is the fastest solution

Comment: Okay thanks... somewhat disappointing but understandable. I restarted and it removed that error from happening, so now I've got a new error! :D

Comment: Don't use open. Pass the file name directly to PdfReader (and don't use PdfFileReader any more, it's deprecated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a context manager, which will close the file as soon as you're done reading it:

```
with open('C:/Users/Jake/Documents/upload_12.5.22_test/'+file_name,'rb') as load_pdf:
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(load_pdf)
```

However, your code should have been correct as shown, since you close the file before you try to rename it. As others have said in the comments, if the file is opened in any other process, Windows won't let you rename it, so the most likely solution is closing other apps or maybe even a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is starting to make more sense. If you could help me clarify for the context manager, is that replacing the for loop, or should it go inside the for loop? Thanks again!

Comment: It replaces the first two lines inside your for loop.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I tried a version with that and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great suggestions here, I really appreciate the help. I was able to get it working on a VBox with Fedora to eliminate any Windows shenanigans, which I am sure will benefit my future coding endeavors as well. The final version I am running is as follows:

````
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger, PdfReader
import PyPDF2
import os

today = '/upload 12.9.22/'

for file_name in os.listdir('/home/jake/Documents/WEEKLY_UPLOAD'+today):
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader('/home/jake/Documents/WEEKLY_UPLOAD'+today+file_name,'rb')
    page_count = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    data_page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = data_page.extractText()
    page_content = page_content.replace('\n','')
    page_content = page_content.split('reports.')
    del page_content[0:1]
    p_c_str = ''.join(page_content)
    p_c_str = p_c_str.strip()
    p_c_str = p_c_str[:-6]
    new_name = p_c_str + " agreement.pdf"
    os.rename('/home/jake/Documents/WEEKLY_UPLOAD'+today+file_name, '/home/jake/Documents/WEEKLY_UPLOAD'+today+new_name)
```
````